# Missing class definition for "input-validation-error" inside a new asp.net mvc-5 web application

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a new asp.net mvc-5 web application using VS 2013. now when i try the built-in login form and i leave the required fields empty i got the following, :-

[image]

where both fields were not highlighted with red color as i use to get inside previous versions of asp.net mvc. now from the generated markup i can inspect that any field that have validation errors will have the following class:-

```
input-validation-error
```

But i search the whole css files which are generated automatically inside my asp.net mvc-5 web application mainly; site.css , bootstrap.css bootstrap.min.css , but i could not find a definition for the input-validation-error ?? so can anyone advice on this please, how i can highlight the fields with red color if they have validation error  , and why this is not the default behavior inside asp.net mvc-5 ?

Comment: Probably `input-validation-error` is added by jQuery validation and is not styled by default. You could add a style in site.css like: `.input-validation-error { border-color: 1px solid red; }`

Comment: @DavidSpence yes this class is added by jquery this is the defualt behavior in asp.net mvc-5. but why asp.net mvc-5 did not add any class definition for the .inout-validation-error , while it is referencing it inside jquery validation ,, could this be a bug in VS 2013 & asp.net mvc templete?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. jQuery validation is used more widely than asp.net-mvc. I think Microsoft have simply did not styled the input when there is an error. Not everyone will want that.

Comment: @DavidSpence but i used to create asp.net mvc-4 web application inside VS-2012 , and these classes definitions were included by default ..

Comment: In asp.net mvc 4 applications there were a lot of default styles in Site.css (including for validation). If you look at Site.css in your new asp.net mvc 5 application you will see it is a lot smaller. Instead, bootstrap css is included and some errors are styled that way. Short answer is that there is no default style for inputs when there is an error in asp.net mvc 5.

Answer (score 15):

> why this is not the default behavior inside asp.net mvc-5

It's not default behavior of ASP.NET MVC 5. You just need to add following css classes in Site.css file.

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using **Bootstrap**, you need to copy the CSS from Bootstrap's validation CSS to the equivalent .NET/jquery classes.

[image: example of bootstrap-styled inputs]

As of Bootstrap 4.5, it looks like this:

**Copied from `.was-validated .form-control:invalid, .form-control.is-invalid`**

```
.form-control.input-validation-error {
    border-color: #dc3545;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='%23dc3545' viewBox='0 0 12 12'%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/%3e%3cpath stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}
```

**Copied from `.was-validated .form-control:valid, .form-control.is-valid`**

```
.form-control.valid {
    border-color: #28a745;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%2328a745' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}
```